# rules of syllogistic logic in an OVS or OSV language

Tags: linguistic-typology, word-order, logic

I am looking to write the present the rules of Aristotelian syllogistic logic in a language that would be unfamiliar to my mostly-American students.  So I thought I would do it in an OVS or OSV language.  So I would like to have a translation of something like

From *All x are y*
and
*Some z are x*, infer
*Some z are y*

I'd be especially interested to find a language in which the translation of *All x are y* has *y* in the sentence before *x*.

Can anyone here help?

Comment: Does it need to be a natural language, or would making up your own notation work too? OVS and OSV languages are extremely rare in the real world, so it may be hard to find one that's also easy for Americans to write/pronounce, doesn't inflect its words in complicated ways, etc.

Comment: The help that we can offer is that OSV and OVS are so rare that nobody that knows such a real language is here. But Klingon is OSV, and surely there are "native speakers" in your class.

Comment: How about from _X and Y are always the same_  infer _X and Y are sometimes the same_?  And reverse. Quantifiers don't always work the way they do in IE languages.

Comment: I prefer a natural language; otherwise, I could make up my own as Draconis points out.  I do have the rules of logic in Klingon and in Nyanja (=Chichewa).   I am teaching about 'formal inference' as something one should be able to do without knowing the meaning of anything involved, as a computer would do.   So I would like a lg which is syntactically different from English regarding the order of the terms x and y.   I *maybe* could use an example like the one jlawler suggests (maybe you remember me from the past, John?), but only if it'd be hard to guess the meaning.

Comment: Do you believe that Pullum lurks here, or that he actually knows Hixkaryana well enough to do translations? I think you didn't understand my comment. Pullum has, AFAIK, never made any claim about Ling SE. Nor has Derbyshire.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think the intended meaning of ‘know’ was ‘is familiar enough with to provide a translation for’ rather than ‘knows of the existence of’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I think you're right. I'd also missed the *that* between*nobody* and *knows* (Thought the wording was odd, but didn't go back to recheck what I'd "read")

Comment: @LarryMoss You don’t need a completely OSV or OVS language to get _y_ before _x_ in the sentence ‘All _x_ are _y_’. Although generally VSO, Goidelic languages (so Irish, Scottish and Manx Gaelic) have the rather unusual quality that classificatory (though not identificatory) copular constructions are VCS rather than VSC, so they will do just fine; e.g., Irish ‘Is _y_ é gach _x_’ or ‘Is _y_ iad na _x_ go léir’.

Comment: I didn't recognize the name, @LarryMoss; I rarely look at them. Of course I remember. You may find my [Logic study guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and [VP study guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf) amusing, or even useful. They're takeaway handouts for linguists learning logic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. Thanks very much, I had not known that the Goidelic languages would provide the examples of the word order in syllogisms that I want.  If anyone wants to help further, please feel free to get in touch.